# Enter blank datetime in a VisualFlow formula

Tags: visual-workflow, datetime

I'm working in a visual flow. I need a formula that will sometimes have current datetime and sometimes be null. The problem is that I can't select a blank datetime and there is no default blank datetime.

It kind of works with date, because I can create a constant that is a date and just leave it blank. But constants cannot have the type datetime.

Another suggestion is to have the update field just be blank. The problem with that is I actually have 5 fields, and I'm never sure which ones are blank and which ones aren't.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually create a variable that is a datetime and just leave the default value blank. Use this where you need it in the formula.